# Visual Studio: wrong reference version

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I downloaded a new version of a third-party dll, copied it to a "Library" folder in a new project, and added a reference. I expect it to show version 5.0.6 in Reference Manager, but it shows 4.5.0.

I have version 4.5.0 on my system, but not anywhere else in the solution or in GAC. It seems to use 4.5.0 at runtime, but copies 5.0.6 to `/bin`.

Please help me understand what is happening.  I provided some supporting details below.

**Update**: I included a screenshot of reference properties per request.

---

dll properties:

[image]

Adding reference by browsing to file location:

[image: Adding Reference]

And here is the resulting reference:

[image: Resulting project references]

Properties:

[image]

If I display the Assembly version at runtime, it shows 4.5:

[image]

But when I look in `/bin`, it has version 5.0.6.

Comment: Why don't you use NuGet to manage your references?  It would certainly help!

Comment: You didn't include a screenshot of the Properties for the reference within your project.  That contains the path to the actual file you are referencing.

Comment: Thank you phillip. I'll look into NuGet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking at (5.0.6.16206) is the `File Version`, not the `Assembly Version`. The File Version is used by the file system and *not* by the .NET runtime. The assembly version is 4.5.0.0 and so what you're seeing is correct, and expected, information.

As Phillip mentioned in the comments, you should look into using NuGet as it makes things a lot easier.

Comment: My error was assuming Product Version = Assembly Version.  I did some testing and now see that they are not the same entity.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Assembly.Load` you should try using `LoadFrom` instead.  Then you won't be depending on it locating the Assembly for you from it's search path.